# How to display the git branch of the current repository when customizing bash?

Tags: bash, git, terminal, prompt

I'm adding this code

```
if [ -f ~/.git-prompt.sh ]; then
  source ~/.git-prompt.sh
  export PS1='\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] $(__git_ps1 "(%s)"): '
fi
```

to get this result.

```
~/apps/project-with-git-repo (develop):
```

But when I go to other folders without a git repository, I see this result.

```
~/apps/folder-without-git-repo (BARE:master):
```

How do I get rid of (BARE:master)? For example, if there is no repository, then do not output git at all

Comment: It's probably easiest to fix this in your `~/.git-prompt.sh` ... which you haven't shown. If you really don't want to change that, you can always just use a `${//}` substitution or `sed` to replace that string ... but you also haven't said what you want it replaced _with_.

Comment: Git itself comes with a rather complicated prompt-setter and other scripts for bash, that does all this for you. If you use that one instead of a private one you won't need to code your own thing, but if you want to use code you write yourself, you need to set `PS1` appropriately based on whether you're in a repository in the first place. That is, you must test: "am I in a Git repo" *before* you attempt to insert the `$(__git_ps1 ...)` output.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
```

Followed by setting `PS1`:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w/\[\033[01;33m\]\$(parse_git_branch) \[\033[00m\]\$ "
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try [ohmyzsh](https://ohmyz.sh) and enable [git plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git)

Comment: The question is about bash.